# Spark Job failing with exit status 15

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to run simple word count job in spark but I am getting exception while running job.

```
    For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1446699275562_0006/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1446699275562_0006_02_000001
Exit code: 15
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=15:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 15
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: root.cloudera
         start time: 1446910483956
         final status: FAILED
         tracking URL: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/cluster/app/application_1446699275562_0006
         user: cloudera
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application finished with failed status
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:626)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:651)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I checked log from following command

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1446699275562_0006
```

Here is log

```
 15/11/07 07:35:09 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: Output directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/WordCountOutput already exists
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/WordCountOutput already exists
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:132)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1053)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:954)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:863)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1290)
        at org.com.td.sparkdemo.spark.WordCount$.main(WordCount.scala:23)
        at org.com.td.sparkdemo.spark.WordCount.main(WordCount.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:480)
15/11/07 07:35:09 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: Output directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/WordCountOutput already exists)
15/11/07 07:35:14 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: SparkContext did not initialize after waiting for 100000 ms. Please check earlier log output for errors. Failing the application.
```

Exception clearly indicates that WordCountOutput directory already exists but I made sure that directory is not there before running job.

Why I am getting this error even though directory was not there before running my job?

Comment: But from stack trace, it is clear that hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/WordCountOutput  already exists.

Comment: Yes ....but checked before running my word count job...directory was not there ....and after running code I got this exception..

Comment: How did you delete the directory? It seems that on S3 at least a meta-file of some sort is always added along with the "directory". So if I add a directory, "myFolder", another meta-file named "myFolder_$folder$" is also added. If I delete only "myFolder" (and not "myFolder_$folder$") and try to run my program again, I will get the error you are seeing.

Comment: I deleted my directory using hadoop fs -rmr /path/to/dir command from hdfs

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: does anyone know the solution

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue and fixed it by adding below highlighted part.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Sentiment Scoring").set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "true");
```

Thanks,
Sathish.

Comment: It is by default true in latest version, but still this error is coming. Ref: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

For us this was caused by "running beyond physical memory limits". After increasing executer memory, the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This Error mostly occurs while you submitting the wrong spark parameter in the spark-submit command. Please check the configuration parameters. In my case, I failed to submit masternamenode address where I need to read resources from HDFS.

Before : Where yarn threw Error- 15
dfs://masternamenode/TESTCGNATDATA/

After: Able to run the application
hdfs://masternamenode/TESTCGNATDATA/